# Abelian Group of Rationals over addition - axiomatic or derived?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, rational-numbers

Sorry if this is a daft question, but if we consider the set of rationals under the 'addition' operator we can form an Abelian Group.

I'm curious: in that situation, is the definition of addition (as given below) derived or axiomatic?

I ask as without knowing the multiplicative inverse of rationals, how can we derive the definition of addition? Moreover, shouldn't they be independent of one another?

Comment: I think the addition comes from the addition of real numbers.

Comment: Is some of your post missing? You say "as given below", but there is no corresponding definition below.

Comment: Thank you to those that edited my original post.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh - Yes, I agree it's defined elsewhere, but in just looking at the Rationals on their own. Is the definition of addition a derived operator or axiomatic?

Answer (score 1):

The addition is defined. More precisely, if you define $\mathbb Q$ as the set of equivalence classes of $\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\})$ with respect to the equivalence relation$$(a,b)\sim(c,d)\text{ if and only if }ad=bc,$$then you *define*$$\bigl[(a,b)\bigr]\times\bigl[(c,d)\bigr]=\bigl[(ad+bc,bd)\bigr].$$This only requires that you know how to multiply (and add) integers.

Comment: Just to add a little something for those curious about this viewpoint: this is an example of the *localization* of a ring. Here we are thinking of $\mathbb{Q}$ as the localization of the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ with respect to the multiplicative system $\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$. For more, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring

Comment: @SamStreeter - Thanks for that. I will look into it :-)

Comment: @Jose - 
Thank you for your post. So, am I correct to infer that the definition of addition is axiomatic?

Comment: @DavidG No. It is defined. I provided a definition, right?!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos - Yes you did. I was just clarifying to make sure I hadn't misinterpreted you. This topic has consumed me, so I hope I don't come across as rude if I ask the obvious! haha

Answer (score 1):

Its a general construction: Each integral domain $R$ can be extended to a field $K$ by using the equivalence relation on $R\times (R\setminus \{0\})$,
$$(a,b)\sim (c,d) :\Longleftrightarrow ad = bc.$$
The equivalence class of $(a,b)$, $b\ne 0$, is
$$\frac{a}{b}  = \{(c,d)\mid (a,b)\sim (c,d)\},$$
the set of all fractions with equal value.
The quotient set 
$$K = \{\frac{a}{b}\mid a,b\in R,b\ne 0\}$$
becomes a field with the operations
$$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} := \frac{ad+bc}{bd}$$
and
$$\frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{c}{d} := \frac{ac}{bd}.$$
The mapping $\phi:R\rightarrow K:a\mapsto \frac{a}{1}$ is a ring monomorphism so that $R$ can be viewed as a subring of $K$. Hope it helps.

Comment: I do not deny that, but forgetting that extension. If we just consider the set of Rationals as a composition of integers. Then is the definition of addition an axiom or is it derived?