# 2 Equivalence class on a function, is the function well defined

Tags: functions

given:

(z1, n1) ∼ (z2, n2) :⇔ z1n2 = z2n1

Equivalence relation on  Z×Z\{0}

(a, b)]∼, [(c, d)]∼ ...  are equivalence classes then we define a function on it

f1([(a, b)]∼, [(c, d)]∼) := [(a + c, b + d)]∼

is f1 well define?

I don't really get it, it's my first seeing an example with 2 equivalence class on a function.

Does that mean for example:

a = 1 b = 2 c = 2 d =1

f1([(1, 2)]∼, [(2, 1)]∼) := [(1 + 2, 2 + 1)]∼

f1([(1, 2)]∼, [(2, 1)]∼) := [(3, 3)]∼

Does this mean I have to check if the elements of [(1, 2)]∼ and [(2, 1)]∼ have a 
partner on [(3, 3)]∼

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Have a look into https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2988327/abelian-group-of-rationals-over-addition-axiomatic-or-derived/2988337#2988337

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, an equivalence class has several representants, for example $(1,1) \sim (2,2) \sim (3,3) ...$

The function $f_1$ is only well-defined if it does not matter which representative we use to compute the sum. It is supposed to be a function that takes a pair of equivalence classes and gives you an equivalence class again.

But: Consider
$$f_1([(1,1)]_{\sim},[(2,1)]_{\sim}) = [(1+2,1+1)]_\sim = [(3,2)]_\sim$$
$$f_1([(2,2)]_{\sim},[(2,1)]_{\sim}) = [(2+2,2+1)]_\sim = [(4,3)]_\sim$$

Since $[(1,1)]_{\sim} = [(2,2)]_{\sim}$, I should get the same result in both cases. But I don't! We can check that $(3,2)$ is not equivalent to $(4,3)$ because $3 \times 3 \neq 2 \times 4$.

By the way, this construction is actually about fractions and the fact that a fraction stays the same if you multiply denominator and enumerator by the same number, as the comment above pointed out.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly if i have a function for example:
same give equivalence relation and everything but the function is like this

f([(a, b)]∼, [(c, d)]∼) := [(ad + bc, bd)]∼


f([(1, 1)]∼, [(2, 1)]∼) := [(1+2, 1)]∼= [(3, 1)]∼

f([(2, 2)]∼, [(2, 1)]∼) := [(2+4, 2)]∼= [(6, 2)]∼


this is a well define function, because 3x2 = 1x6?

Comment: Exactly, the function $f1$ is not well-defined because you cannot add fractions like this (by adding numerator AND denominator), but the function you give in this comment is fine.